# Writing a report of cpp file in txt format with same name as file name

Tags: c#

I am reading files from a directory and reading all text and generating reports separately for each file. I want report name same as file name.

I have tried to get file name but when I pass it to reporting module it gives exception error.

```
 string path = "D:\\AssertCount\\";
 foreach (string sFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
 {
     assertCount=0;
     reportingCounter++;
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
     string fileName = files[reportingCounter];
}
```

ReportWriting(totalWords, assertCount,fileName);

here is complete report writing module

```
public static void ReportWriting(int totalWords, int assertCount,string fileName)
{
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("D:\\AssertCount\\Reports\\"+fileName+".txt");
    file.Write("TotalWords = " + totalWords);
    file.Write("\nAasserts = " + assertCount);
    file.Write("\nOccurence of assert keyword in code is " + assertPercentage + " % ");
    file.Close();
}
```

followin exception occurs

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect : 'D:\AssertCount\Reports\D:\AssertCount\testData2.cpp.txt''
```

Comment: May I ask why you're getting all the files in the foreach loop for each file? This looks redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Directory.EnumerateFiles() and Directory.GetFiles() return full paths, not file names. You could try replacing

```
string fileName = files[reportingCounter];
```

with

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[reportingCounter]);
```

to turn the full path into just the file name, without the extension (since you add on ".txt" later).

---

Alternatively, you're already enumerating the files in the directory with the `foreach`, so why not just use sFile?

```
foreach (string sFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
{
    assertCount=0;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFile);
    ReportWriting(totalWords, assertCount,fileName);
}
```

Comment: index out of range exception can I show you my complete code so that I don't have to search for more. I have been doing this for 4 hours

Comment: Sure, if you're okay with that, go ahead. Just keep in mind, this error (index out of range) is probably unrelated to your initial file paths problem

Comment: Problem Solved, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You're duplicating the path:
`'D:\AssertCount\Reports\D:\AssertCount\testData2.cpp.txt'` (It should be just `'D:\AssertCount\testData2.cpp.txt'`

The variable fileName already includes the full path to the resource (not only the file name). So you could just delete "D:\AssertCount\Reports\"  from the creation of the StreamWriter object. The code would be like this

```cs
    public static void ReportWriting(int totalWords, int assertCount,string fileName)
    {
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName+".txt");
        file.Write("TotalWords = " + totalWords);
        file.Write("\nAasserts = " + assertCount);
        file.Write("\nOccurence of assert keyword in code is " + assertPercentage + " % ");
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The only problem with this is, they are passing in `D:\AssertCount\testData2.cpp`, but they want to save the file to `D:\AssertCount\Reports\testData2.cpp.txt`, if I understand correctly. So they need to add the "Reports" directory in between the filename and "AssertCount", IMO the easiest (although not very extensible) way to do this is to just pass in the filename itself as parameter, instead of the whole path